# Codeigniter query not forming properly

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, hash, sha256

I wrote a query with a sha2 hash function in codeigniter, but the resultant query is not forming properly.

**Here's my code in model :**

```
public function validate_user($data = NULL)
{
    $email = $data["email"];
    $password = $data["password"];
    $this->db->select('user_id');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('sha2(username, NULL)' => $data["username"], 'password' => $password));
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

**And here's the error I'm getting ( due to malformed query ) :**

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''FCD8FE02F495400DC020499AC31FC75ABA05005622FD7A2F01D37153724CB395' AND `password' at line 3

SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE sha2(username, NULL) 'FCD8FE02F495400DC020499AC31FC75ABA05005622FD7A2F01D37153724CB395' AND `password` = '2668dcd9bac3c8bb60742f139876d1d6'
```

Why is the `=` symbol not coming between `sha2(username, NULL)` and `'FCD8FE02F495400DC020499AC31FC75ABA05005622FD7A2F01D37153724CB395'`

The actual query should turn out to be :

```
SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE sha2(username, NULL) = 'FCD8FE02F495400DC020499AC31FC75ABA05005622FD7A2F01D37153724CB395' AND `password` = '2668dcd9bac3c8bb60742f139876d1d6'
```

And not :

```
SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE sha2(username, NULL) 'FCD8FE02F495400DC020499AC31FC75ABA05005622FD7A2F01D37153724CB395' AND `password` = '2668dcd9bac3c8bb60742f139876d1d6'
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Is username stored as plain username or as sha2() value?

Comment: And second question, I can check ( [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-algos.php) ) `sha1`, `sha224` `sha256`, `sha384` and `sha512` hash algorithms, but no `sha2`. Where does `sha2()` come from?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tpojka. The username is stored as plain text in the database, but my client will be sending sha256 of the  username, so the only way I guess to check it is by using sha2 function of mysql ( the reason being I was checking and I realized that the sha256 value client sends and sha2 generated by mysql were the same, given a particular username)

Comment: And in my query, I'm writing `sha2(username, NULL)` within single quotes to pass it to mysql as it is, so that mysql will run it's own sha2 function to generate a hash of the username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a simple query and using Codeigniter methods to build the statement is not helping in this case.

Try using a much simpler bound query like this one.

```
$sql = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE sha2(username, 256) = ? AND `password` = ?";
$query = $this->db->query($sql, array($data["username"], $data["password"]));
return $query->row_array();
```

Note I put in the second parameter to the mysql `sha2()` call. I think both params are required and if either is missing or null then `sha2()` returns null.